# RSA Public Key Conversion with just Modulus

Tags: c, openssl, rsa, public-key

I received an RSA-2048 bit public key (256 bytes) as a file which contains just those 256 bytes. Which function in SSL enables me to load this key as an RSA structure so I can convert it to another format? This is in C code using openssl source.

I think it's the DER format, but I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: If you have only 256 bytes, you first have to find out what the used public exponent is supposed to be (3 or 65537 or something else).

Comment: I'm checking to get the exponent information. Assuming I have that, what else do I need to convert/load this?

Comment: If it's 256 bytes, it's not DER. It's just a raw big integer.

Comment: Related: http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/How-to-create-a-RSA-private-key-from-raw-data-td4020.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just put this together and it seems to work correctly:

https://github.com/JonathonReinhart/rawrsa

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>

static const char* appname;

static void print_bn(const char *what, const BIGNUM *bn)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    char *str = BN_bn2hex(bn);
    printf("%s (hex): %s\n", what, str);
    OPENSSL_free(str);
#endif
}

static void usage(void)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s modulus-file exponent\n", appname);
}

#define err(fmt, ...)   \
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: " fmt, appname, ##__VA_ARGS__)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    appname = basename(argv[0]);

    if (argc < 3) {
        usage();
        exit(1);
    }

    const char *modfile = argv[1];
    const char *expstr = argv[2];

    /* Read modulus */
    FILE *mf = fopen(modfile, "rb");
    if (!mf) {
        err("Failed to open \"%s\": %m\n", modfile);
        return 1;
    }

    unsigned char buf[256];
    if (fread(buf, sizeof(buf), 1, mf) != 1) {
        err("Failed to read %zu bytes of modulus\n", sizeof(buf));
        return 1;
    }

    fclose(mf);

    BIGNUM *mod = BN_bin2bn(buf, sizeof(buf), NULL);
    if (!mod) {
        err("BN_bin2bn() failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    print_bn("Modulus", mod);


    /* Parse exponent */
    BIGNUM *exp = NULL;
    if (BN_dec2bn(&exp, expstr) == 0) {
        err("BN_dec2bn() failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    print_bn("Exponent", exp);

    /* Create RSA key */
    RSA *rsa = RSA_new();
    if (!rsa) {
        err("RSA_new() failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    rsa->e = exp;
    rsa->n = mod;

    /* Write PEM-encoded RSA public key to stdout */
    if (!PEM_write_RSAPublicKey(stdout, rsa)) {
        err("PEM_write_RSAPublicKey() failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I use [`BN_bin2bn`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BN_bin2bn.html) to create an OpenSSL bignum from raw binary data from a file. This is where we load your 256-byte modulus.

Then, I use [`BN_dec2bn`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BN_dec2bn.html) to create a bignum from the exponent provided on the command line.

Next, I create an RSA object with [`RSA_new`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_new.html), and set the public exponent (`rsa->e`) and modulus (`rsa->n`).

Finally, I write the RSA public key to a PEM file with [`PEM_write_RSAPublicKey`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/PEM_write_RSAPublicKey.html).

**Example:**

```
$ scons -Q
gcc -o main.o -c -Wall -Werror -g main.c
gcc -o rawrsa main.o -lcrypto

$ ./rawrsa key.bin 65537
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEA9cFHSTQ6h1Ls/vx7B+V/84XVlLxUU1dU1mEr9ROAqWrZtfasvx2E
21lbva+AdJ/B4u6fGVhCEMgekXsRB65CqZfwL3DFL6tqam6GvrOyvZgAlQKrA54w
DaKMT8Kfg2I2K9W/HCkCOHczhuHhjFmeiV9BuQgpmcPcNz6UXBwU05d3g6oM/X4m
lEhEsaH4bqo1qsMX6jp6WnsR13GEfsYoYVmHgEbnKJyGpsoRVW6HQXLHvef9XLEJ
v9n7nLdHToya75svxJ3v9JugD3n6PiC48085/FWb9980o4hmG9iW5rehm4Dlui8c
TDnHkQSrvi9WLlZ+S8hdtwDRN/pVVTjgPAIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: I was 75% through to what you have after not finding anything else in my searches. Thanks for confirming I was on the right track to get it done myself.

Comment: @David No problem. Good to hear. I use Git repos all the time, even for stupid little tests, so once I had it working it was nothing to clean it up and push it to Github.

Comment: You should probably call [`RSA_check_key`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_check_key.html) to ensure you guessed the exponent correctly. If it fails, maybe try the other usual suspects: 3 and 17.

Comment: @jww Thanks, but it appears that is only for private keys. From your link: "It does not work on RSA public keys that have only the modulus and public exponent elements populated." I don't think you *can* know if you guessed e correctly.

Comment: @Jonathon - My bad... I think you are right (I even seem to recall a segfault when trying to use it without the CRT parameters). I'll get a bug report filed against OpenSSL for it.